# Reverse Bernoulli Trial?

Tags: probability

I'm struggling to figure out how to do what I think would be called a reverse Bernoulli trial, essentially:

> How many coin flips must I make to have a 75% change of getting three heads?

First of all, does this even make sense as a thing to try to work out? As for my attempts so far, I've tried expanding the binomial ${n \choose j}$, taking the log of the whole thing and using Stirling's approximation on the $ln(n!)$-like terms, but I get horribly tangled up and can't see a way round.

Does anyone have a method to do what I'm trying to? Does it have a name?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you mean exactly a $75$ percent chance of getting exactly three heads, at least a $75$ percent chance of getting exactly three heads, exactly a $75$ percent chance of getting at least three heads, or at least a $75$ percent chance of getting at least three heads?  (The first three are impossible with a fair coin, by the way.)

Comment: Ah, I realise the question was badly posed now. I meant the last one, the number of flips required to have at least a 75% chance of getting at least three heads. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the normal approximation of the binomial distribution, which states that the binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ converges to a normal distribution with mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$.

This approximation is "good" if $n$ is large, so either you ask for many heads, or a probability close to $1$.

Now let's say we can make this approximation: the number of tails is $N\sim\mathcal{N}(np,np(1-p))$. So 
\begin{align}
P(N\geq 3)&=0.75\\ &\iff P\left(\frac{N-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}<\frac{3-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\right)=0.25\\&\iff \frac{3-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}=\Phi^{-1}(0.25)\end{align}

Where $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard Gaussian distribution. Now you have to solve this in $n$.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the way I will go as I will be using the result on a system with very large $n$ and $j$, I asked about coin flips to try to understand how things work.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently, how many coin flips to have less than 25% chance of getting $0,1,2$ heads.

For n flips, probability of $X<3$ heads is:

$\Pr[X<3] = \Pr[X=0]+\Pr[X=1]+\Pr[X=2]= {n \choose 0}2^{-n}+{n \choose 1}2^{-n}+{n \choose 2}2^{-n} = \left[1+n+\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]\dfrac{1}{2^n} = \dfrac{n^2+n+2}{2^{n+1}} < \dfrac{1}{4}$

By trial and error, for $n=6,\Pr[X<3]=\dfrac{44}{128}>\dfrac{1}{4}$ while for $n=7,\Pr[X<3]=\dfrac{58}{256}<\dfrac{1}{4}$, so you will need 7 flips.

Comment: The question is about of getting three heads. In my opinion there has to be exactly 3 heads.

Comment: You won't be able to get as high as 75% for exactly three heads, as you will need more than five trials (five gives less than 50%).

Comment: Maybe you are right, but this doesn´t fit your answer better